# Insert into Table B from Table A using Distinct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables

Table A

```
NameID  FirstName  MiddleName  LastName  Addr1  Addr2  Phn1  Phn2  City  State 
NULL      Micheal    Calvin      Dodson    12     23     1234  123  XYZ   ABC    
NULL      John       NULL        Keith     NULL   NULL   2344  NULL SQE   FDG    
NULL      John       NULL        Keith     NULL   NULL   2344  NULL SQE   FDG 
NULL      William    Stephen     NULL      45     NULL   NULL  NULL HJD   ABC
NULL      Victor     NULL        Anthony   NULL   NULL   NULL  NULL NULL  NULL
```

Table B

```
NameID   FirstName  MiddleName  LastName  Addr1  Addr2  Phn1  Phn2  City State Zip Email Gender...
```

I need to get the distinct records of (FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) of Table A and insert the same details along with the other fields matching with Table A into Table B.
My Table B has NameID as an identity coloum. So after inserting a unique record into Table B, I need to get that NameID and insert it back into Table A shown below :

TABLE A

Table A

```
NameID  FirstName  MiddleName  LastName  Addr1  Addr2  Phn1  Phn2  City  State 
1         Micheal    Calvin      Dodson    12     23     1234  123  XYZ   ABC    
2         John       NULL        Keith     NULL   NULL   2344  NULL SQE   FDG    
2         John       NULL        Keith     NULL   NULL   2344  NULL SQE   FDG 
3         William    Stephen     NULL      45     NULL   NULL  NULL HJD   ABC
4         Victor     NULL        Anthony   NULL   NULL   NULL  NULL NULL  NULL
```

TABLE B

```
NameID  FirstName  MiddleName  LastName  Addr1  Addr2  Phn1  Phn2  City State Zip  Email Gender...
1       Micheal    Calvin      Dodson    12     23     1234  123   XYZ   ABC   NULL NULL  NULL
2       John       NULL        Keith     NULL   NULL   2344  NULL  SQE   FDG   NULL NULL  NULL
3       William    Stephen     NULL      45     NULL   NULL  NULL  HJD   ABC   NULL NULL  NULL
4       Victor     NULL        Anthony   NULL   NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL
```

Can you please help me with this. Im not able to get this query right. Code in SQL Server 2008

Thanks in advance,
Sunitha

Comment: Is NameID also auto-incrementing?

Comment: Do all the fields for a record in TableA need to match to be grouped together or just the FirstName, MiddleName, LastName?  What if there are two records with the same FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, but the other fields are different - for example Phn1 is different but the names and other fields are the same.

Comment: NameID is an indentity Column in Table B and is auto incremented

Comment: Only FirstName,MiddleName,LastName should be matched. There wont be a scenario where other fields are different but FirstName, MiddleName and LastName are distinct.

Comment: This seems like a pretty dangerous assumption. If you have two different John Smiths are you willing to discard one of them entirely? Also is TableB starting empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is with two queries.  The first problem is handling duplicates in TableA.  The following query selects an arbitrary row for each name combination:

insert into TableB()
       select ()
       from (select a.*,
                    row_number() over (partition by FirstName, MiddleName, LastName order by FirstName) as seqnum
             from TableA a
            ) a
        where seqnum = 1

Then, update the original table:

```
update TableA
    set NameId = (select max(NameId) from TableB
                  where TableB.FirstName = TableA.FirstName and
                        TableB.MiddleName = TableA.MiddleName and
                        TableB.LastName = TableA.LastName
                 )
    where NameId is null
```

If your fields contain NULL values (rather than blanks), you can use coalesce() for the join conditions:

```
update TableA
    set NameId = (select max(NameId) from TableB
                  where coalesce(TableB.FirstName, '<null>') = coalesce(TableA.FirstName, '<null>') and
                        coalesce(TableB.MiddleName, '<null>') = coalesce(TableA.MiddleName, '<null>') and
                        coalesce(TableB.LastName , '<null>')= coalesce(TableA.LastName, '<null>')
                 )
    where NameId is null
```

Comment: Can you tell me how coalesce() works in this scenario? I could insert into TableB(), but updation in TableA() happens only when the FirstName,MiddleName and Lastname are not NULL.

Comment: Can you tell me how to reduce the cost of this query. Currently when I am using the update Table A using COALESCE, Its taking loads of time. Though the number of records in Table A is 307125 and Table B is 239384

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @results TABLE
(
  NameID INT, 
  FirstName VARCHAR(32), -- guessing on data types for these columns 
  MiddleName VARCHAR(32), 
  LastName VARCHAR(32)
);

;WITH x AS 
(
 SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, 
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
   ) --, ... other columns ...
   FROM dbo.TableA
)
INSERT dbo.TableB 
(
  FirstName, MiddleName, LastName --, ... other columns ...
)
OUTPUT 
  inserted.NameID, inserted.FirstName, 
  inserted.MiddleName, inserted.LastName
INTO @results
SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName --, ... other columns ...
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;

UPDATE a SET NameID = r.NameID
  FROM dbo.TableA AS a
  INNER JOIN @results AS r
  ON COALESCE(a.FirstName,'') = COALESCE(r.FirstName,'')
  AND COALESCE(a.MiddleName,'') = COALESCE(r.MiddleName,'')
  AND COALESCE(a.LastName,'') = COALESCE(r.LastName,'');
```

Comment: This is not working since at times FirstName/MiddleName/LastName has null values and I am getting the errror as follows :  ""Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MiddleName', table '@results'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.""
Moreover, I cannot make the FirstName, MiddleName,LastName in the @results table as nullable since we cannot define Primary Key constraint on nullable column in the table

Comment: We're guessing on data types, we're guessing on nullability... in the future please post table definitions so we don't have to guess.